# Counting the number of instances from Attribute

Tags: java, attributes, instance, arff

I'm trying to count the number of instances from a specific attribute in a `.arff` file. Although, I can only seem to select the attributes and not the values from the data where it appears.

In this case, I'm trying to select the number of times Wins appear in the data, however, the code only selects for the value `Wins` in the attribute.

Here's what I'm using:

```
//create the class to load the data
package weka;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class DatasetLoading {

  public static Instances loadData(String location) {
    try {
      return DataSource.read(location);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to load data from: " + location);
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dataLocation = "C:/Users/Emil/Downloads/Week 1/Arsenal_TRAIN1.arff";
    Instances train = loadData(dataLocation);
    System.out.println(train);
  }
}

//select for counts of values that appear in the data

public class test_learning {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String arff = "C:/Users/Emil/Downloads/Week 1/Arsenal_TRAIN1.arff";
    Instances data = DatasetLoading.loadData(arff);
    System.out.print("Num of Wins = " + data.attribute(2).value(2));
```

> Output: Num of Wins = Win

Expected:

> Output: Num of Wins = 12

Example of datafile:

```
@relation Arsenal-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R3

@attribute Leno {0,1}
@attribute Tierney {0,1}
@attribute class {Loss,Draw,Win}

@data
1,0,Loss
1,0,Loss
0,1,Draw
1,0,Draw
0,0,Win
0,1,Win
1,1,Win
0,1,Win
1,1,Win
1,0,Win
1,1,Loss
0,1,Draw
1,1,Draw
1,1,Draw
0,0,Win
1,0,Win
0,1,Win
1,1,Win
1,1,Win
1,1,Win
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of retrieving the third nominal value of the third attribute ([Javadoc](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#value-int-)), you could use the `Instances.attributeStats(int)` method ([Javadoc](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#attributeStats-int-)) to get the statistics for the third attribute ([AttributeStats Javadoc](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/AttributeStats.html)).

Comment: Thank for the response, though I'm having difficulties understanding which is perhaps my lack of experience. When you mention ```Instances.attributeStats(int)```, does this infer that I must create a constructor to take the statistical values from an attribute? so far, I have tried implementing: ```data.attributeStats(2)```, however, it returns: ```Type  Nom  Int Real     Missing      Unique  Dist  C[0] C[1] C[2]
 Nom 100%   0%   0%     0 /  0%     0 /  0%     3     3    5   12```

Comment: Instead of just outputting the string representation of the `AttributeStats` object that the `attributeStats(int) method returns`, you need to retrieve the correct statistic from that object of course (that's why I linked to the Javadoc). For retrieving the counts for the third label of the third attribute, you probably need to do something like this to retrieve that value: `data.attributeStats(2).nominalCounts[2]`.

Comment: You're a great teacher! I'm self-learning java and weka and your explanations are great. I'm getting used to interpreting the documents and all your comments have been tremendously helpful, they work just as expected!